# Using Amazon VPC

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I have a static website that is built in `Amazon EC2` and deployed to `Amazon S3`. How to control the traffic to this site by setting up `subnets` and `gateways` using `Amazon VPC`?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the traffic by doing below points.

1.Create own VPC with required CIDR range or you can edit your default VPC

2.Create Internet gateway and attach your VPC to reach the internet

3.Create subnets and choose your preferred VPC and give CIDR range

4.create Network ACL and edit you rule : Give inbound as your subnet CIDR range and outbound as your static web page or open to the world(0.0.0.0/0). associate your subnet in subnet association option.(You can control the traffic based on ports also).

5.Create route table and associate your subnets which you want to connect.